# how to build and eval a postfix stack for expressions that contain functions with optional parameters

Tags: c#, stack, expression, postfix-notation

For example:

```
3 + 4 * max(2, avg(6, 8, 2, 4,...), 6, ...)
```

My first thought is to create a special token that is the count of the parameters and push it into the stack when ")" is encountered.  But I am not sure how to keep count when the parameters themselves could be functions with parameters.

Comment: I think I don't need the actual count.  All I need is a token that mark the beginning of the parameter.  For example, the postfix expression for 3+4*max(2,3,avg(6,8)) will be(3,4,Mark,2,3,Mark,6,8,Avg,Max,*,+).  During evaluation, operator avg will know to stop @ mark when popping for parameters.  So will the operator max.  I think this could work!  Anyone with a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by slightly modifying the Shunting-yard algorithm and inserting a special token (called @) to the output stack right after any prefix operations.

For example: 4 * max(2, avg(6, 8), 32) + 3 will generate an output stack of:
+ 3 * Max 32 Avg 8 6 @ 2 @ 4

When evaluating this stack from left to right, function Avg will know to stop popping operand when it seems the first @ token, so will the function max.